# How to use Google Mock to mock gettimeofday()

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am doing a unit test for my C++ application. One of the methods which my unit test case calls is the `gettimeofday()`. Currently, I have a mockclass.cpp where I add my mocked gettimeofday as shown below:

mockclass.cpp:

```
namespace speed{
    int mock_gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz){
        return 12345678;
    }
}
```

realcode.cpp:

```
namespace speed{
    static void A(){
        struct timeval tp;
        gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    }
}
```

I am referring to this [website](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/issues/1078) to solve the issue. At the moment, even I tried the link from the website, it's still using the real `gettimeofday()` instead of my mocked `gettimeofday()`. I am using the namespace method as mention on the website.

Comment: Which solution do you use? Preprocessor `#define` or different linking for production code and for tests? If former, how do you compile the project, do you have something like `target_compile_definitions`? If latter, in your example I don't see any `gettimeofday` fake implementation that you can link with.

Comment: @pptaszni I am using the namespace method.

"If you use C++ you can solve this with namespaces:

`namespace myproject
{
    int gettimeofday(struct timeval *restrict tp, void *restrict tzp);
}`
Now you can create two implementations:

The production one, calling the real gettimeofday()
The mocked function
Finally link the 2nd to your tests (where mock is necessary)."

Answer (score 1):

You should implement 2 different `myproject::gettimeofday` functions (and use explicitly `myproject::gettimeofday(tv, tz);` in your production code) in 2 different translation units:

implementation for production (e.g. `production_time.cpp`):

```
namespace myproject
{
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
  return ::gettimeofday(tv, tz);
}
}
```

implementation for testing (e.g. `testing_time.cpp`):

```
namespace myproject
{
int gettimeofday(struct timeval*, struct timezone*)
{
  return 12345678;
}
}
```

Then you can make some shared/static library out of it, and you can link your project with either production or testing implementation. I don't know what kind of build system you use, but it terms of CMake it might look like this:

```
add_library(MyProject <sources>)
add_library(ProductionTimeUtils production_time.cpp)
add_library(TestingTimeUtils testing_time.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main MyProject ProductionTimeUtils)
target_link_libraries(test MyProject TestingTimeUtils)
```

Alternatively you can create an interface

```
class MyTimeUtils
{
public:
  virtual ~MyTimeUtils() = default;
  virtual int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz) = 0;
};
```

And inject it as a dependency to your production class.